# azure kubernates service managed service for application log management

Tags: azure, azure-aks

**problem statement.** 
as per my understanding, we can run an elastic search, kibana and logstash etc as a pod in kubernates cluster for log management. but it is also memory heavy intensive application. AWS provides various managed services like Cloudwatch, cloud trail and ELK stack for log management.
do we have a similar substitute in Azure as well i.e. some managed service?

Answer (score 0):

you can use AKS with Azure Monitor ([reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview)). I'm not sure you can apply this to not AKS cluster (at least not in a straight forward fashion).

[Onboarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-onboard) (for AKS clusters) is really simple and can be done using various methods (portal included).

You can read more on the docs I've linked (for example, about capabilities).

Comment: thanks for your response. these links highlight about monitoring but not about pushing logs generated inside the container to some centralize manage service

Comment: they do offer container logs as well, do take some time to at least open the links I've provided :) for example [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-live-logs) can be found under the same section

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Monitor for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview) is available now and once integrated some cluster metrics as well as the logs will be automatically collected and made available through log analytics.